# elapsed time executed program in python returned complex number

Tags: python

i want to calculate elapsed time in a line of my python program.

```
start = time.time()

#do something here

end = time.time()

elapsed = end - start

print(elapsed)
```

i get complex number instead of floating number.i expect to get float number but i get complex number.how i can convert complex number to float number?
i tried to use timeit library but result is same.when i tried to write a script in gedit i get correct result but it not worked in main program.whats wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "get complex number"? Can you please show us an example of the output you get?

Comment: `time.time()` does not produce a complex number, it does give a (real) floating point value. Please give a proper [repro] and also add the exact output you are getting to your question.

Comment: i get for example : elapsed=1.6775653e - 4.8765733

Comment: @roiksail, Does it really look like `1.6775653e - 4.8765733`? Python floats look like `1.6775653e-4` when in scientific notation (i.e., with an integer after the `e`), or otherwise just plain `0.001324`. However, you can get something that looks a little bit (but not exactly) like this if you print two numbers without any space in between.

Comment: Given the unlikely output, it's really time you create a proper [mcve] to show us. Also please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1):

`1.6775653e-4.8765733` is in *exponent* (or [scientific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)) notation and is equal to `1.6775653 * 10⁻⁴.⁸⁷⁶⁵⁷³³`.

That is, about `0.00002` seconds.

With that said, it's unlikely that Python would print a value with an exponent containing fractions.

Comment: I don't think Python would ever give a number with a floating-point exponent!

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

def elapsed_time(start, end):
    hours, rem = divmod(end-start, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(rem, 60)
    print("Elapsed Time: {:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:05.2f}"
                .format(int(hours),int(minutes),seconds))

#Test

start = time.time()
# your prgram

end = time.time()

elapsed_time(start, end)
```